# How to configure VueGapi as global in Vue 3 App

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to use the [VueGapi](https://vue-gapi.github.io/vue-gapi/#requirements) plugin for a gmail app in Vue. Here is my main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueGapi from 'vue-gapi'

const app = createApp(App).mount('#app')

app.use(VueGapi, {
  apiKey: 'my_key',
  clientId: 'my_client_id',
  discoveryDocs: ['https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4'],
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
})
```

When I try and reference it with `this.$gapi` I get the
`Uncaught TypeError: this.$gapi is undefined`

A little new to Vue so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's unknown where you use it and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.mount` function does not return a vue app, that's why you can"t make a `use` after.

You have to first `create`, after `use` and to finish `mount`:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueGapi from 'vue-gapi'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(VueGapi, {
    apiKey: 'my_key',
    clientId: 'my_client_id',
    discoveryDocs: ['https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4'],
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
})

app.mount('#app')
```

Also you have to be sure to use Vue 3 (check vue version in your `package.json`) and to use the corresponding `vue-gapi` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-gapi)